# How does the Peano axiom construct only the set of Natural numbers but no other set

Tags: math

I am beginning real analysis and stacked on the first page (Peano Postulates)
It reads as follows at least on my textbook.

Axiom 1.2.1 (Peano Postulates). There exists a set N with an element 1 E N and a function s: N -> N that satisfy the following three properties.
a. There is no n E N such that s(n) = 1
b. The function s is injective.
c. Let G is subset of N be as set. Suppose that 1 E G, and that g E G then s(g) E G. Then G = N.

Definition 1.2.2. The set of natural numbers, denoted N, is the set the existence of which is given in the Peano Postulates.

My question is, from my understanding of the postulates we could construct infinite set which satisfy the three properties.
For example
Odd = {1,3,5,6,...} or
or = {1,5,25,635....} with a different s(n) off course, but s(n) is not defined anyway in the postulates.
How is those properties uniquely identify the set of the Natural numbers?

Comment: Please post this at https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Comment: It does not define N as you know it, but any N defined this way can be used like N. If you teach children to show you increasing number of fingers and count "1, 5, 25, 125, 625" (i.e. what we consider "*5" instead of "+1") then it can be used like 1,2,3,4,5. It is basically an agreement. s(1) is called 2 or 5, s(s(1)) is called 3 or 25. (By the way, I do not see the logic in your 635, but that is actually irrelevant.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.